# Scroll through XML content example

Tags: android

Can someone point me to an Android example with source that allows the user to scroll through the contents of an xml file that contains text entries (preferrably with arrows on the side of the screen that allow previous/next type of interaction)

I've looked through the examples on the Android site and didn't see anything similar. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated (I'm an Android newbie but experienced Java developer)

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt you are going to find a nice Android walkthrough of exactly the problem you are trying to solve, so you'll probably need to extrapolate from a few different guides.

Parsing xml is not substantially different from parsing xml anywhere else.  This [guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html) talks through the 3 different ways of doing so.  Depending on how large your xml is, you can decide which makes the most sense for you.

In terms of UI, not sure exactly what you are looking for, but a ListView is often a good way to display large chunks of data.  See [Hello ListView](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html).

Or, if you want a single text area that scrolls with 2 buttons, see [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) api.  Its pretty simple.  [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) is a good guide to basic layout.  You could probably accomplish what you want with a few nested LinearLayouts, or a RelativeLayout.  If you post an attempt, people can help you fix it up.